# Strange, unwanted entry in printer dialog (Brother HL2270DW)

Tags: printing, brother

I got this wireless printer and got it working without issues on 13.04, but since I upgraded to 13.10 there has been this weird issue with the printer and I haven't been able to find any help because I don't even know what to search for.

Basically, the problem is the additional entry that appears in the print dialog.

[image]

As you can see, there are three printers listed:

- Print to file
- The printer I added (located in "2nd Option"). This is how it looked in 13.04.
- A third, weird, out of nowhere printer that does nothing except crash
  the printer if it's simply selected (no additional dialogues or anything, it just messes up the printer and I have to reset it because it stops working for other people in the network)

Until recently, that third entry seemed to do nothing, but now it shows the status message `TONER LOW`, but the printer I usually choose to print doesn't show anything. The toner is in fact low, but I don't know why that message appears in that unusable printer entry and not the usable one.

As for that number that is the useless printer's name, I couldn't find it anywhere except in the "New printer" dialog:

[image]

If I add the printer choosing the first option under Network printer(BRW00...), the added printer doesn't work (it's there but it does nothing). If I choose the second option(BRN30...), the added printer works as intended. Regardless of the choice, the weird printer will still show up in the print dialog.

The entry I wish to get rid of doesn't appear in the libreoffice print dialog for some reason.

I don't know if the problem lies with cups, the printer drivers, or some botched installation of the drivers, but I'd appreciate any help from anyone who might know what's going on. Although I can somehow live with this issue, I worry that I will accidentally select the weird printer and be forced to reset it completely.